# Apple Application Loader + Adobe AIR: Cannot proceed with delivery

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, app-store-connect, application-loader

When trying to upload new iOS app version from Apple Application Loader it says:

> Cannot proceed with delivery: an existing transporter is currently
>   uploading this package

I see this has solution if I was using Xcode for native iOS project. But I'm using Adobe AIR + Flex compiler. Flex SDK 4.13.0, FlashPlayer16
Using the same configuration before I did not have any problems.
Targeting swf 27.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem does not have anything to do with Adobe AIR.
You have to delete one hidden file that is located in the Mac OS X from which you upload the app.
First unhide the hidden files by typing in the terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Then delete the .token file from:

```
/Users/<username>/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try increasing the version number in your app and iTunes connect and try uploading the new binary.

Comment: thanks..I'll try it. itunesconnect is down at the moment. I hate Apple so much..their system is soo bad